# How to conditionally hide logo from wordpress header if logged in?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, conditional-statements

I have added current user's avatar to my Wordpress header (using shortcode) and now want to remove my logo if someone's logged in. The effect should be that their avatar (logo) is replacing the default one.

I figure I have to add something to the theme's header.php file (after copying it into child folder - or maybe add the code directly to functions.php instead).

I really have no clue about this, and have just seen snippets of php and css code that might be relevant (and I don't know how to translate that css into php):

```
// I know this is wrong but how to change the CSS?
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    <id="logo"
    #logo {
    display:none;
    }
}
?>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In header.php enter liks this it may help you...

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
 ?>
<style>
    #logo {
    display:none !important;
    }
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work. I copied header.php to child theme and tried adding the code in several places, including immediately after the php referring to ( $ gp_logo ).

Comment: if the site is live send the url

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this

```
if( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    <div class='logo'>
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return get_avatar( $user->ID, 90 );
    </div>
}else{
    <div class='logo'>
        your logo here....
    </div> 
}
```

if the user will be logged in it will replace your logo with user's logo, use the condition like this....

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work for me. I'm not sure if I was supposed to add something where you put "use the avatar of user here now" or "your logo here...." I just stripped these out but no luck.

Comment: use avatar of user logo and your logo here are just comments u have to put your code here i dont know your code

Comment: ok, I just used the 'if' part and added the line from the avatar shortcode that has worked for me previously: 
    if( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        <div class='logo'>
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        return get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 90 );
        </div>
    } 
But unfortunately still didn't work.

Comment: use $user->ID instead of $current_user->ID

Answer (score 0):

```
    #header .logo {
display: none !important;
}
```

try to add this in custom css

or

i am using this to hide page for logged in Users

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_redirect_page' );

function check_redirect_page() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 10 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 5 ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

you must try it for logo

Comment: Ta but needs to be conditional (i.e. if user is logged on).